# redirect in twilio with ruby

Tags: ruby, sinatra, twilio

I am new to both Twilio and Ruby and am trying to figure out how to "redirect" or send a request to another url. I don't need to Gather data at this step but simply evaluate a parameter passed and send it in one direction or the other.  Any help?

```
 post '/ors_verified/ors/:ors_number' do |ors_number|
     number_correct = params['Digits']
     if number_correct == '1'
          redirect "/how_many_irt/ors/#{ors_number}"
     else 
          redirect '/how_many_ors'
 end
 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the issue was that I needed to wrap it into a twillio response.

```
 post '/ors_verified/ors/:ors_number' do |ors_number|
    number_correct = params['Digits']
   Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
    if number_correct == '1'
      r.Redirect "/how_many_irt/ors/#{ors_number}"
    else 
      r.Redirect '/how_many_ors'
    end
   end.text 
end
```

Comment: One thing to watch out for if you see retrieval errors is to match your HTTP methods. The default is POST and will not complete if your destination method is defined as GET.

Answer (score 2):

you could use: `redirect_to`instead of `redirect` so

```
post '/ors_verified/ors/:ors_number' do |ors_number|
 number_correct = params['Digits']
 if number_correct == '1'
      redirect_to "/how_many_irt/ors/#{ors_number}"
 else 
      redirect_to '/how_many_ors'
 end
end
```

Comment: tried that but i get: ''NoMethodError - undefined method `redirect_to' for #<Sinatra::Application:0xb656609c>:''

Comment: I have also seen people use redirect_to :action => '/url' but that does't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be using sinatra a redirect should look like this:

```
 post '/ors_verified/ors/:ors_number' do |ors_number|
     number_correct = params['Digits']
     if number_correct == '1'
          redirect to("/how_many_irt/ors/#{ors_number}") # <-- notice the #to
     else 
          redirect to('/how_many_ors') # <-- notice the #to
     end
 end
```

The `#to` basically creates another object from your string which sinatra can act on.
You can read about sinatra redirects [here](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Browser%20Redirect)